# Modify error output to include test name, test path, current URL

Tags: testcafe

I would like to add the test name, test path and current URL to my error messages, so that they would show with the `Browser:` and `Screenshots:` info. Is this possible, and how?

Example of what I would like to have:

```
- Error message -
AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

Test name: This is my test name
Test path: C:\e2e-testing\tests\test.js
Test URL: <current_test_URL> 

Browser: Chrome 112.0.0.0 / Windows 11
Screenshot: C:\e2e-testing\screenshots\2023-04-20_10-48-53\test-1\Chrome_112.0.0.0_Windows_11\errors\1.png

37 | stacktrace here
```

Could I do it with a custom reporter or with hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onBeforeWrite` hook to modify the reporter output. The default `spec` [reporter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402825/guides/intermediate-guides/reporters) does not offer information about the specific page where an error occurred. However, you can explore [community reports](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402825/guides/intermediate-guides/reporters#community-reporters-and-custom-reporters) that offer such information and also use a hook to customize their output.

See the help topic describing [Modify Reporter Output](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404388/guides/advanced-guides/modify-reporter-output#process-different-reporter-events).